# Display Error in while loop in Java

Tags: java, loops

I need to write a program with a loop that lets the user enter a series of positive integers. The user should enter -99 to signal the end of the series.   After all the numbers have been entered, the program should display the largest and the smallest numbers entered.Use “The greatest of a set of numbers” algorithm(see below) to solve the problem.

My problem is that I also need to output an error when the user only enters -99:

User input (1 number):  -99
Produces output “No numbers were entered”

```
Scanner keyboard =  new Scanner(System.in);

int num;
System.out.println("Enter a number ( press -99 to quit)");
num = keyboard.nextInt();
int max = num;
int min = max;

while (num != -99){
    System.out.println("Enter a number ( press -99 to quit)");
    num = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (num < 0 ){
        System.out.println("No numbers were entered");
    } else if ( num > max) {
        max = num;
    } else if ( num < min) {
        min = num;
    }  
}
System.out.println("the largest number: "+max);
System.out.println("the smallest number: "+min);
```

When I run it and enter only -99, I get this:

```
the largest number: -99
the smallest number: -99
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation so your code looks like it makes sense?

Comment: I just realized that! sorry.

Comment: num = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (num < 0 ){
        System.out.println("No numbers were entered");
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a do-while to clean up the inputs, and you can move the "error message" outside the loop, after the break condition.

```
Scanner keyboard =  new Scanner(System.in);
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

int num;
boolean entered = false;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a number ( press -99 to quit)");
    if ((num = keyboard.nextInt()) == -99) {
        if (!entered) {
            System.out.println("No numbers where entered"); 
        } 
        break;
    } 
    if (num > max) max = num;
    if (num < min) min = num;
    entered = true;
} while (num != -99);

if (entered) {
    System.out.println("the largest number: "+max);
    System.out.println("the smallest number: "+min); 
}
```

Personally, I think you should use `keyboard.next()` and allow a user to input `"quit"`, while also allowing -99 as a valid value

Comment: When I run it I get this:
Enter a number ( press -99 to quit)
12
Enter a number ( press -99 to quit)
34
Enter a number ( press -99 to quit)
-99
No numbers where entered. 

 My program has to output something like this:
Input 2 numbers: 1 , -99 Output: the largest number: 1 ; the smallest number: 1
Input 5 numbers :1 , 2 ,55, 0,-99 Output: the largest number:55; the smallest number:0

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try This one:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        List<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int number, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(in.hasNextInt()){
            number=in.nextInt();
            if(number!=-99){
                numbers.add(number);
                if(number>max)
                    max=number;
                if(number<min)

                    min=number;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        if(numbers.size()==0){
            System.out.println("No numbers were entered");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("the largest number: "+max);
System.out.println("the smallest number: "+min);  
        }
    }
}
```